# A nice numbr theoretic problem

Tags: number-theory

T(n) is sum of all prime divisor of n. Find all n $\in N$ such that: $T(n) = T(2^n+1) $

I know a closed fomula for computing the sum of the divisors.... But i dont know about prime divisors an dont have an idea to proceed. Plase help me...

Comment: What do you mean by " a closed formula for computing the divisors " ?

Comment: I  mean sum of the divisrs

Comment: Upto $n=200$ , the only solution is $n=3$. Considering that $2^n+1$ is much larger than $n$, this should be the only solution.

Comment: Do you count multiplicity? Is the sum of prime divisors of $8$ equal to "2" or to "6=2+2+2" (because $8=2^3$)?

Comment: No multiplicity

Comment: Let $n=\prod p_i^{a_i};\ 2^n+1=\prod p_j^{b_j}$ There are two general cases. First case, all $p_i=p_j$ (that is $n$ and $2^n+1$ have the same radical or kernel). There is some hope of finding such solutions systematically; for example, in many such cases $n\mid 2^n+1$. Second case, there are at least some $p_i$ without corresponding $p_j$ and vice versa. This seems to me to be a very difficult problem, for which I see no systematic approach.